# Ms Word File names with spaces

Tags: vba, file, ms-word, space

I am trying to open a Ms Word file thru `VBA(Visual Basic Application) Command`. It runs fine as long as file name does not contain spaces, so I cannot open files with path names like this

```
-->  C:/Users/Mch/Desktop/blaa blaaa.docx
```

and i get error message like this

> -->  Description: Sorry, we couldn?t find your file. Is it possible it was >moved, renamed or deleted?
>   (C://Users/Mch/Desktop/blaa%20blaa...)

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: It seems that you have made some form of string conversion before opening the document. The spaces have been replaced with "%20" and the Open command can't interpret it correctly. To help you further we need to see the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in the filename shouldn't matter.  Here's a quick sample:

```
   Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\some folder\test document.docx")

   objWord.Visible = True
```

Comment: It fails when you pass a string to objWord.Documents.Open that contains spaces, not if you pass it a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

Still failing in 2022

```
 MyWordTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Path & "Annual Maintenance Development Plan - Template.docx"

 objWord.Documents.Open MyWordTemplate
```

Crashes with error
--> Description: Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Is it possible it was >moved, renamed or deleted? (W:%Annual Maintenance Development Plan - Template.docx)

I tried wrapping it in quotes, still doesn't like the space